# django. Get only current day. Only day without time

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to get current day for now. Only day. For example today is 20-March i need use it in my queryset

```
query = self.filter(Q(busyrooms__end_date__day=datetime.now().date()),
                    Q(reservedrooms__end_date__day=datetime.now().date()))
```

Tried to use `datetime.now().date()` but i got error

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.date'

Comment: `datetime.now().day`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the current day from datetime_obj by accessing the `day` attribute of datetimeobj  like `datetime.now().day`

Answer (score 6):

In `django` most of the cases we use timezone. so, it's recommended to use `timezone` .

```
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.now().date()
timezone.now().day
```